# popoto.js query all labels with same relationship without choosing a property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using popoto.js and try to query my database like this:

```
MATCH (t1:Tag)-[l:EXPERT_LINKED_TO]->(t2:Tag) RETURN t1, l, t2
```

Problem is, that I can only query in popoto.js with a WHERE-clause. So I have to choose a specific Tag for querying the DB.

But I want to get all Tags who are in a relationship with other tags without to specify a property.

So is there a way to query the DB without setting a property in popoto.js?